# Django DateTimeField show Date and Time input in the same line in admin

Tags: django, django-admin

Suppose I have a model with `DateTimeField`.

And for `DateTimeField`, currently admin input is:

[image]

Is it possible to customize it to
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by overriding the admin css. You basically have to `.vDateField`, `.vTimeField` elements.
Create a template `admin/change_form.html` in your templates folder. Add the following lines to that file

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% block extrastyle %}
.vDateField, .vTimeField {
    display: block;
}
{% endblock %}
```

Django picks up this file, reads it and processes it before processing the original template file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is not work initially. I reference to your answer and make some changers, and it finally work as expected. -->
.datetime br{
    display:none;
  }

Answer (score -1):

As you can see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets)

```
fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': (('first_name', 'last_name'), 'address', 'city', 'state'),
        }),
)
```

first_name and last_name fields will display on the same line

Comment: Sorry but I am not splitting the field to date and time, it is one DateTime field.