# Names of DJango admin form components

Tags: python, django, user-interface

I am trying to re-arrange an admin form and add a button to do die rolling in the center of it. I'd like to keep the original functionality of controls. Most likely in another setting this would be done with some sort of java jiggery pokery but I'd rather just do it with django.

I figure the simplest (if not easiest) way to get what I want would be to just do a custom admin form. But I am not sure what some of the controls are called so I've been having a time trying to find out how to set them up.

Essentially this is a financial investment for a LARP I am involved in. Each Investment was done by a character (foreign key) against an institution (also foreign key). The player invests an amount of money. The staffer takes the money and rolls a die adding a modifier for the institution that is hidden from the player in a table and changes according to what is going on for that institution. If the die roll is X, they get Y result which determines if they lose their investment, get it back or make a profit.

I want to re-arrange the form a little. For example having amount, die result, investment result and a button for rolling all in one central section. I'd also like to get the date/time editor all on one line because having it as two separate lines looks janky. Having the foreign key edit/view/add widget there is preferred - I just don't know what it is.

Can someone advise? Or perhaps I'm making this more difficult than it needs to be?

Attached is a picture of what I'm talking about.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to update the UI, you're going to need to to [override the template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates), especially if you are looking to add a JS random number generator that fills the form field. You'll need to update the CSS to get the datetime on the same line, [possibly answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30479416/django-datetimefield-show-date-and-time-input-in-the-same-line-in-admin).

You could also consider using [a default method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#default) on the field to generate the dice roll.

The UI elements you are wondering about are [related model widgets](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/widgets/related_widget_wrapper.html). You can control whether they appear using [the different has permission methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_add_permission).